# How to lazy load a Text property in app engine low level datastore api?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using the app engine low level datastore apis. At some point I wrote a Text object into an entity and stuck it in the datastore like this:

```
Text text = new Text("foo");
Entity entity = ...;
entity.setUnindexedProperty("xyz", text);
datastore.put(entity);
```

When I pull that entity out of the datastore, does the Text property automatically get read from the datastore?:

```
Key key = KeyFactory.createKey(...);
Entity entity = datastore.get(key);
```

or does it not incur any overhead until I touch it?:

```
Text text = (Text)entity.getProperty("xyz");
```

I'm wondering because I'm storing a large piece of text in this property, and I don't need it that often. I'm not sure if I can reduce my billing costs by selectively loading the property (actually I don't see in the billing where doing something like this would save me any money):

https://developers.google.com/appengine/pricing

but anyway maybe it would reduce the time of the request,

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it gets read.  You can see the current state of your data using the "Datastore Viewer" link in the [admin console](https://appengine.google.com).

Unindexed fields won't increase the cost of reads or queries but they can increase the storage fee.